# Cannot iterate through object in Ubuntu PHP 5.2.10-2 Works on PHP 5.2.10?

Tags: php, ubuntu, versioning, wamp

With this code I am iterating through an object.

Works:

- Windows with WAMP and PHP 5.2.9
- Linux web server with PHP 5.2.10

It is not working on my desktop:

- Ubuntu 9.10 with PHP 5.2.10-2 from
  the repo's

> ```
> $incomingData = json_decode($_POST['data']);
>
> foreach($incomingData as $key => $action)
> {
>
> }
> ```
>
> Invalid argument supplied for
>   foreach()

Comment: what is the outputted version of phpinfo(); ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe one of your servers has magic_quotes_gpc enabled, so you can try to use stripslashes on $_POST['data'] before you decode it. Both PHP versions should be able to iterate through objects.

Comment: If this fixes it, you really ought to fix whichever server has magic_quotes_gpc enabled, and turn it off (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc)

Comment: Thanks! Adding stripslashes did the trick! The data I was decoding had indeed backslashes in it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you've got your PHP versions right?

From the documentation for [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

> As of PHP 5, it is possible to iterate
> objects too.

Try using [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/json_decode) with the second argument set to `true`, to make `json_decode` return associative arrays rather than objects.

```
$incomingData = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
```

Where the second argument, `$assoc` (defaults to `false`) means:

> When `TRUE`, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

My guess is that one box has less than PHP 5.

To confirm that's the issue, try changing `$incomingData` to some kind of innocuous associative array:

```
$incomingData = array("foo" => "bar", "baz" => "monkey");
```

and see if that makes the error go away.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm sure I got the versions right. I added the argument to json_decode and edited my code but it produces the same error.

Answer (score 0):

try doing:

```
$data_array = get_object_vars(json_decode($json_data));

print_r($data_array);

this is only if you obtain information from some web page such as

$data = file_get_contents('http://www.someurl.com/somerestful_url/');
$data_array = get_object_vars(json_decode($data));
print_r($data_array);
```

also, you were probably trying to do json_encode, but instead put json_decode($_POST['data']);

unless you have json string inside of $_POST['data']; it will not work.