# Odd behavior of json_decode()

Tags: php, json

Take the following JSON string (generated by some ExtJS code - but that's irrelevant):

```
[{"action":"Setting","method":"toggle","data":["welcome-home"],"type":"rpc","tid":2},{"action":"ContentExtFeFillout","method":"todo","data":[true,0,8,false],"type":"rpc","tid":3}]
```

being sent to a server as a `POST` request and retrieved via `$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']`.

Running

```
json_decode($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']);
```

on our development machine (`5.2.10-2ubuntu6.4` with Suhosin Patch `0.9.7`) gives a correct `print_r()` output of:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [action] => Setting
            [method] => toggle
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => welcome-home
                )

            [type] => rpc
            [tid] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [action] => ContentExtFeFillout
            [method] => todo
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 8
                    [3] =>
                )

            [type] => rpc
            [tid] => 3
        )
)
```

Running the same code on a client's production machine (`5.2.5` with Suhosin Patch `0.9.6.2` and Zend Optimizer; SUSE Linux by the way) gives the following `print_r()` output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [action] => Setting
            [method] => toggle
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => welcome-home
                )

            [type] => rpc
        )

    [1] => 2
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [action] => ContentExtFeFillout
            [method] => todo
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 8
                    [3] => 
                )

            [type] => rpc
        )

    [3] => 3
)
```

Note the missing **`tid`** property which obviously has been moved into the main array as an own value - this naturally breaks all the following code.

We also downloaded a Windows PHP version `5.2.5` to check if there's a bug in `json_decode()` but we get the correct output here.

Are there any known issues with `json_decode()` at all that could cause this odd behavior?

We're currently totally clueless...

Thanks to all of you!

Best regards

Stefan

Comment: Is there any difference in var_dump()'ing of $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'] on the different machines?
Or you have only difference after json_decode()'ing?

Comment: Json_decode'ing on Vista with PHP 5.2.5 (cli) without Suhosin yields the correct result.

Comment: `$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']` is exactly the same on both machines. We logged the `HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` and used the exact same string on our machines to `json_decode()` it and it returned the correct result. Unfortunately we don't have direct access to the client's machine so we're down to logging only.

Comment: @Gordon: so does PHP 5.2.5 (cli, no Suhosin) on my Windows 7 machine and several other PHP installations (Mac, Linux) we tried. Currently the client's machine is the only one that produces this weird error. 

Actually I don't know where to look into... We have retrieved the output of `phpinfo()` but I don't know of any configuration directives that might trigger this behavior.

Comment: @Stefan does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860025/cannot-iterate-through-object-in-ubuntu-php-5-2-10-2-works-on-php-5-2-10 - I really have no clue either, but maybe it's related to magic_quotes_gpc too

Comment: @Gordon: Nope - `magic_quotes_gpc` if off on the production machine. Thanks for your efforts - I'm as clueless as you are...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK guys - problem solved. Lacking any more options we persuaded the client to update the installed PHP version and guess what: it works.

There seems to have been a subtle bug in their PHP installation (PHP, Zend Optimizer and/or Suhosin) which has been fixed with the update. Still, a quite weird thing.

Thanks to all of you!

Best regards

Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried swapping the tid and type keys? Also how about using a hardcoded variable to check if the problem could be with $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']?

Try the following:

```
$t1='[{"action":"Setting","method":"toggle","data":["welcome-home"],"type":"rpc","tid":2},{"action":"ContentExtFeFillout","method":"todo","data":[true,0,8,false],"tid":2,"type":"rpc"}]';
print_r(json_decode($t1));
```

Comment: It's quite difficult as we don't have direct access to the machine (it's an enterprise internal machine) - so we can only use logging and they'll send us the log files by mail. 
I might by tempted to exclude a problem with `$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']` because what we actually do is: `log($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'])`, `$data = json_decode($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'])` and `log(print_r($data, true))`. The JSON string above is the exact string that has been logged - and so is the output of `print_r($data, true)`.